# C++ GUI window has shapes drawn that the code isn't supposed to draw

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I am using the GUI library to make a tic-tac-toe game. I store my game data in a 2D array, called CP. In CP, 0 is an empty slot, 1 is an O, and 2 is an X. After emptying CP, and redrawing the board, making the array equal to:

`000
000
000`

the window looks something like this, with the ones representing an X or O that was there before:

`010
101
010`

The code for resetting the CP, and painting the board is attached here:

```
switch( message )
{

case WM_PAINT:
    {

        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

        Rectangle( hdc, 0, 0, 200, 200 );
        Rectangle( hdc, 200, 400, 0, 600 );
        Rectangle( hdc, 600, 0, 400, 200 );
        Rectangle( hdc, 600, 400, 400, 600 );
        Rectangle( hdc, 200, 200, 400, 400 );

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(CP[i][j] == 1) {
                    Ellipse(hdc, 200 * i, 200 * j, 200 * (i + 1), 200 * (j + 1));
                }
                if(CP[i][j] == 2) {
                    MoveToEx(hdc, 200 * i, 200 * j, NULL);
                    LineTo(hdc, 200 * (i + 1), 200 * (j + 1));
                    MoveToEx(hdc, 200 * (i + 1), 200 * j, NULL);
                    LineTo(hdc, 200 * i, 200 * (j + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
    }
    return 0;
    break;

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            CP[c][b] = 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "RESET\n";
    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
    turn = 1;
    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

1. tell Windows to erase the background using `RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INVALIDATE);`
2. erase all of the grid background yourself. Currently, you draw filled rectangles for five of the cells to create the grid, the four cells not being erased are the cells in the grid you don't fill the background of - changing the brush to a different colour makes this obvious :
   [image: board with red brush and data {0,1,2,0...}]